# Rails 3 - Setting up an Account Controller w Views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a Rails 3 App with Devise...

I want to create a Account controller that will allow the user to update their account, things like Profile, Account, Notices, Password, etc...

Here's what I've done so far.

I generated an account controller which gave me the following:

**Routes:**

```
  get "account/profile"
  get "account/password"
  get "account/notices"
```

**Views**
now exists given the names above with /views/account/...

**My Controller**

```
class AccountController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def profile
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
  end

  def password
  end

  def notices
  end

  def privacy
  end

  def disable
  end

end
```

**View for Account Profile:**

```
<% form_for @user, :html => { :multipart => true} do |f| %>
```

Problem is that makes the form like:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/13" class="edit_user" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="edit_user_13" method="post">
```

And I want it to be like `/account/profile/update` which is where the form should post?

This is the first time I've done something like this. Am I down the right track? How do I add the /account/profile/update part? Add something in the route and change the form tag??? Is there a cleaner way to do this in the route?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should stick to RESTful routes when possible.  Instead of having URLs like `/profile/123/update`, the RESTful alternative would be `/profile/123` using HTTP `PUT`

read this for more info on RESTful routes in Rails 3: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Also, take a look at using nested resources in your routes for profiles, notices, etc (section 2.7 in the rails doc):

```
resources :accounts do
  resources :profiles, :notices
end
```

For example, doing an edit using a nested resource will give you routes like this:

```
/accounts/123/notices/3/edit
```